# How to loop over nested json response typescript Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngfor

Given below the JSON response which I receive from the rest Endpoint.

```
{"image_2_11_0-51-upgrade.iso": {"model": "somemodel", "hostnames": ["abc.com", "abcd,com"], "upload_status": false, "version": "2.11.0-51"}, "image_2_11_0-51-upgrade.iso":     {"model": "newmodel", "hostnames": ["my.com"], "upload_status": false, "version": "2.11.0-51"}}
```

I wanted to display like below in an HTML li using ng-for  [Angular 2]

image_2_11_0-51-upgrade.iso    somemodel       abc.com,abc.com    false  2.11.0.51

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please provide code.

Comment: let me try it, can you provide some sample result

Answer (score 0):

This is Just a Example Structure of Binding using ngFor:

**Important : You have to Change your `image_2_11_0-51-upgrade.iso` key to some string key. Because, this type of key can make error.**

Your Response Here

```
{
  "image_2_11_0-51-upgrade.iso": 
  {
    "model": "newmodel",
    "hostnames": [
    "my.com"
    ],
  "upload_status": false,
  "version": "2.11.0-51"
  }
}
```

Assign this Response to One Variable, (ex variable: ResponseVariable)

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let list of ResponseVariable.image_2_11_0-51-upgrade.iso.hostnames;let i = index">{{list}}</li>
</ul>
```